# Alt+Ctrl+T no longer opens a terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys

I have a problem with keyboard shortcuts such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>. They don't work anymore. I have logged out, logged in, rebooted, powered off completely, and restarted Compiz several times. But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> does not open a terminal or anything else.

Can anyone suggest a fix or what I should look at?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing I would recommend is checking the settings in Keyboard, which is found in System Settings under Hardware section.

You will see here that the setting is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. If this is different on your system, just click on it and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to reassign it.